# How to connect an API to R Studio

Tags: r, http-headers, http-status-code-403, bearer-token

I'm trying to connect the API to my **R** studio. After executing the below code I got the error 403:

> Access Denied due to Invalid Authorization.

```r
apiKey <- "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6ImQ2YzliYjRmLTIwZmMtNDc3NS1iMTYxLWNmMzgzZWMyYThmYSIsImlhdCI6MTYzODgzMDY2Miwic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyLzU1M2E1ODA1LTA1YzctNTQyZS00MjAyLTY4NjNkYjZmYjg0OCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJicmF3bHN0YXJzIl0sImxpbWl0cyI6W3sidGllciI6ImRldmVsb3Blci9zaWx2ZXIiLCJ0eXBlIjoidGhyb3R0bGluZyJ9LHsiY2lkcnMiOlsiODQuODIuMjA5LjMiXSwidHlwZSI6ImNsaWVudCJ9XX0.lUSKahV0RJR23NHQmEQJopkp31qwD3VcGqr8gBVTIEt0Hg3cK4AMg00kGVD9NFqXhUmnEOeQtLug2ZJcsXCYbQ" 

url <- "https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/players/%238QUYQ8/battlelog" 

headers <- c('Content-type' = 'application/json',
             'Accept' = 'application/json',
              'authorization' = 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTMxOGY3LTAwMDAtYTFlYi03ZmExLTJjNzQzM2M2Y2NhNSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGwiLCJhdWQiOiJzdXBlcmNlbGw6Z2FtZWFwaSIsImp0aSI6ImQ2YzliYjRmLTIwZmMtNDc3NS1iMTYxLWNmMzgzZWMyYThmYSIsImlhdCI6MTYzODgzMDY2Miwic3ViIjoiZGV2ZWxvcGVyLzU1M2E1ODA1LTA1YzctNTQyZS00MjAyLTY4NjNkYjZmYjg0OCIsInNjb3BlcyI6WyJicmF3bHN0YXJzIl0sImxpbWl0cyI6W3sidGllciI6ImRldmVsb3Blci9zaWx2ZXIiLCJ0eXBlIjoidGhyb3R0bGluZyJ9LHsiY2lkcnMiOlsiODQuODIuMjA5LjMiXSwidHlwZSI6ImNsaWVudCJ9XX0.lUSKahV0RJR23NHQmEQJopkp31qwD3VcGqr8gBVTIEt0Hg3cK4AMg00kGVD9NFqXhUmnEOeQtLug2ZJcsXCYbQ')
```

The curl code is working well. Here below is the curl code:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header "authorization: Bearer <API token>" 'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/players/%238QUYQ8/battlelog'
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't post your actual API key on a public forum.

Comment: This is not enough information to help with this request. Have you checked the developer reference material for the service you are trying to request data from? API calls are not standard or plug and play... you need to make sure you're requesting data from the API exactly as the service wants to accept the request. Also, you should be using paste instead of c. C is creating a vector, but you just want a character string which is generated with paste.

Comment: Also, you haven't executed an API call in the code above. Is there a get request that you sent somewhere?